# Print Arabic or other charset in System.out

Tags: java, character-encoding, arabic

I'm tyring to print a String with Arabic characters:

```
private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    try {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "ISO-8859-6");
        ps.println(String.format(msg, args));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException error) {
        System.err.println(error);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

However, I see from the Eclipse log console that the Arabic characters as displayed as series of these kind of characters `èååêÒÉ`

What could be missing in my code?

Comment: You can try something like that: `String arabicString = new String("كيف حالك".getBytes(), "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    try {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        ps.println(String.format(msg, args));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException error) {
        System.err.println(error);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String arabicString = "كيف حالك";
    print(arabicString);
}
```

Comment: "كيف حالك" is "How are you" in arabic formal language.. just in case you were wondering ;)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the console you use to display the output is also encoded in ISO-8859-6. In Eclipse , you need to go to Run Configuration > Common to do this.