# How to handle Arabic in java

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection

i need to pass a string of arabic value to the HttpURL as a parameter but before i do say when i print the message its showing only question marks

```
public void sendSms(SendSms object) throws MalformedURLException,ProtocolException,IOException  {

    String message=new String(object.getMessage().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(message);//printing only question marks
}
```

and even when i send the message as url parameter its not sending the original message as arabic its sending the question marks.

```
public void sendSms(SendSms object) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException,IOException  {

    String message=new String(object.getMessage().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(message);
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.print(message);
    String charset="UTF-8";


    URL url = new URL("http://62.215.226.164/fccsms_P.aspx");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en,ar_KW;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
    String urlParameters =       "UID=test&P=test&S=InfoText&G=965"+object.getPhone()+"&M= Hello "+object.getName()+" "+message+" &L=A";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Arabic or other charset in System.out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644247/print-arabic-or-other-charset-in-system-out)

Comment: @YoungMillie as mentioned in question i dont only need to print the arabic.  printing arabic after converting to "utf-8" is just a test

Comment: System.out.println will *show* your characters as `?` in a Windows command window, but that doesn’t mean they are actually question mark characters.  It just means the command window cannot display the actual characters.

Comment: @VGR   okk then  how can i be sure that i am passing Arabic string to the URL and even converting the String as "String message=new String(object.getMessage().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(message)" its printing only question marks

Comment: Instead of using System.out.println, use a [Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).  Then you can [add a Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler-java.util.logging.Handler-) to your Logger (or the root Logger) which [writes to a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html), and you can examine that file.

Comment: i did test it a other way when i am hitting the url from browser directly with meassage  "some arabic" its working fine but when i pass it from a java program i am getting only question marks.

Comment: @VGR Please post an answer made from your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `SendSms.getMessage()` returns a `String`, what did you intend with this line?

```
String message = new String(object.getMessage().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Encoding and decoding the message is a waste at best—if it works, you will just get back the string you started with. And it will only work if the default encoding is UTF-8. In this case, it's corrupting the message.

When you encode a `String` with `getBytes()`, the platform default encoding is used. Unless the system's native character set supports Arabic, any Arabic character will be replaced with a supported character, usually `?`.

Try this instead:

```
String message = object.getMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need to follow the advice in erickson’s answer.  If there is still a problem, read on…

A Windows command window is pretty limited in what characters it can display. I don’t know how various language packs and code pages affect it, but I know an English edition of Windows will display Arabic characters (and most characters above U+00FF) as `?`.

So it’s entirely possible that your characters are correct, they are just being shown as `?` when printed.

Instead of using System.out.println, use a [Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html). Then you can [add a Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler-java.util.logging.Handler-) to your Logger (or the root Logger) which [writes to a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html), and you can examine that file:

```
private static final Logger logger =
    Logger.getLogger(SmsSender.class.getName());

// ...

public void sendSms(SendSms object) throws IOException {

    String message = new String(object.getMessage().getBytes(),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    logger.info(() -> "Message=\"" + message + "\"");

    // ...

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    logger.info(() -> "Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    logger.info(() -> "Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    logger.info(() -> "Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

(By the way, MalformedURLException and ProtocolException are both subclasses of IOException, so you only need `throws IOException` in your method signature.  It inherently covers the other two exceptions.)

In some other class, presumably in your `main` method:

```
int logFileMaxSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;  // 10 MB
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(
    new FileHandler("%h/Sms-%g.log", logFileMaxSize, 10));
```