# Sending Arabic over HTTP post as parameter not working

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I hit a URL with an Arabic parameter value (like below):

```
http://62.215.226.164/fccsms_P.aspx?UID=something&P=somethingS=InfoText&G=96567771404&M=اخص شقث غخع خن ؤخةث&L=E
```

It works perfectly; I get the message on a phone in Arabic. When I try to achieve the same through the following code, though, I only get question marks in the message.

```
public void sendSms(SendSms object) 
    throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException
{
    String message = new String(object.getMessage().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(message); // This also prints only question marks
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.print(message);

    String charset="UTF-8";

    URL url = new URL("http://62.215.226.164/fccsms_P.aspx");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en,ar_KW;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
    String urlParameters = "UID=test&P=test&S=InfoText&G=965" + object.getPhone() + "&M= Hello " + object.getName() + " " + message + " &L=A";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
 }
```

To get the message in Arabic, what do I need to add or change in the code?

Comment: Please [do not ask the same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729307/how-to-handle-arabic-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send Arabic data as parameter you need to encode this data to UTF-8.

You can use following code to get the proper output.

```
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
  bw.write(urlParameters);
  bw.flush();
  bw.close();
```

The problem occurred in the following code. So replace your code below with the code above.

```
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
  wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
  wr.flush();
  wr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because http doesn't support the characterset,
your browser handles url-encoding automatically,
In your code you need to encode each parameter separately because of special characters eg. asuming object.getMessage() does not return ???:

```
String message = URLEncoder.encode(
""اخص شقث غخع خن ؤخةث",
java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() );
```

And then concatenate:

```
String urlParameters = "UID=...&M=" + message + "&L=A";
```

Comment: If the platform default character encoding does not support Arabic (which it doesn't appear to do in the case), this will just encode a bunch of question marks. Use the version that accepts an character encoding name, and isn't deprecated.