# Write Persian Text to pdf via PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to write persian text to pdf via PDFBox, however, pdfbox separates and reverse separated charachters. how should i fix that? ( i use pdfbox pdfbox-2.0.19 )

here is my code:

```
                 PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
                 PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
                 doc.addPage(page);
                 PDPageContentStream cont = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                 cont.beginText();
                 PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(doc, new File("C:\\Users\\farhad\\Downloads\\vazir-font-v24.1.0\\Vazir.ttf"));
                 int fontSize = 15;
                 cont.setFont(font, fontSize);
                 String text = "برنامه نویس ایرانی هست اینو بلد باشه؟";
                 float x =  50;
                 float y = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() / 2;
                 cont.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
                 cont.showText(text);
                 cont.endText();
                 cont.close();
                 doc.save("D:\\pdf.pdf");
```

and I atatched a screenshot which shows the result.

[image]

Comment: You're printing it left to right.  What happens if you reverse the string before printing it?

Comment: @cup Nothing changes. again it separates characters and reverses them

Comment: Does it print properly if you use printstream?  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644247/print-arabic-or-other-charset-in-system-out  Just trying to isolate whether it is the pdf driver or whether you need to render before printing.

Comment: Complex scripts are not supported. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4189

Comment: @cup I did some manipulation with Unicode characters and fixed the issue ;)

Comment: Post your solution and mark it as the answer.  The problem with the character set is there are 4 representations of each letter depending on what's to the left or right of it.  There is a unicode character set with all 4 forms.  To render, you'd normally check left and right and choose the correct one.  That way all the characters will join up.

Comment: @cup exactly ;)

Answer (score 3):

## for those of you who seeking the answer of this question:

you should do some manipulation with Unicode characters.
Every Persian character that you normally know (for example س ش ت ظ), actually has 4 different forms and each form has its own Unicode characters.

- initial form
- medial form
- final form
- isolated form

Let's say the word  سا

in this case, the initial س has a Unicode character which is different than the س in راس which comes at the end of the word.

for better understanding, look at the picture below

[image]

## how can you get Unicode characters of each form?

just go to this website https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/ and search your character.

please note that, Arabic and Persian **almost** use the same script, that's why in the picture that I uploaded, it says "**Arabic** letter Seen isolated form" for س character.

Here is a class that you can use to calculate 4 different forms of Persian characters:

```
 public class PersianCharachtersUnicode {

    char c;
    private String InitialFom_Unicode;
    private String MedialForm_Unicode;
    private String FinalForm_Unicode;
    private String IsolatedForm_Unicode;


    public void setCharc (char c) {
        this.c = c;
        calculate();
    }





    private void calculate() {

        switch (c) {

        case 'آ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\0";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFE81";
            break;

        case 'ا':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFE8E";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFE8D";
            break;


        case 'ب':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFE91";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFE92";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFE90";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFE8F";
            break;


        case 'پ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFB58";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFB59";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFB57";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFB56";
            break;


        case 'ت':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFE97";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFE98";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFE96";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFE95";
            break;


        case 'ث':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFE9B";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFE9C";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFE9A";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFE99";
            break;


        case 'ج':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFE9F";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEA0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFE9E";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFE9D";
            break;


        case 'چ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFB7C";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFB7D";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFE9B";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFB7A";
            break;


        case 'ح':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEA3";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEA4";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEA2";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEA1";
            break;


        case 'خ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEA7";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEA8";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEA6";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEA5";
            break;


        case 'د':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEAA";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEA9";
            break;


        case 'ذ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEAC";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEAB";
            break;


        case 'ر':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEAE";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEAD";
            break;


        case 'ز':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEB0";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEAF";
            break;


        case 'ژ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFB8B";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFB8A";
            break;


        case 'س':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEB3";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEB4";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEB2";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEB1";
            break;


        case 'ش':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEB7";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEB8";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEB6";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEB5";
            break;


        case 'ص':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEBB";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEBC";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEBA";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEB9";
            break;


        case 'ض':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEBF";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEC0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEBE";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEBD";
            break;


        case 'ط':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEC3";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEC4";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEC2";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEC1";
            break;


        case 'ظ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEC7";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEC8";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEC6";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEC5";
            break;


        case 'ع':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFECB";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFECC";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFECA";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEC9";
            break;


        case 'غ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFECF";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFED0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFECE";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFECD";
            break;


        case 'ف':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFED3";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFED4";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFED2";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFED1";
            break;


        case 'ق':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFED7";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFED8";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFED6";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFED5";
            break;


        case 'ک':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFB90";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFB91";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFB8F";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFB8E";
            break;


        case 'گ':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFB94";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFB95";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFB93";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFB92";
            break;


        case 'ل':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEDF";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEE0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEDE";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEDD";
            break;


        case 'م':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEE3";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEE4";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEE2";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEE1";
            break;


        case 'ن':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEE7";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEE8";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEE6";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEE5";
            break;


        case 'و':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\0";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\0";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEEE";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEED";
            break;


        case 'ه':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFEEB";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFEEC";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFEEA";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFEE9";
            break;


        case 'ی':

            InitialFom_Unicode    = "\uFBFE";
            MedialForm_Unicode    = "\uFBFF";
            FinalForm_Unicode     = "\uFBFD";
            IsolatedForm_Unicode  = "\uFBFC";
            break;


        default:
            break;
        }

    }




    /**
     * @return the initialFom_Unicode
     */
    public String getInitialFom_Unicode() {
        return InitialFom_Unicode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the finalForm_Unicode
     */
    public String getFinalForm_Unicode() {
        return FinalForm_Unicode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the isolatedForm_Unicode
     */
    public String getIsolatedForm_Unicode() {
        return IsolatedForm_Unicode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the medialForm_Unicode
     */
    public String getMedialForm_Unicode() {
        return MedialForm_Unicode;
    }
 }
```

Comment: [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/home) can help you doing those replacements. See also [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48346903/1729265) dealing with the same issue for Arabic writing.

Comment: @mkl ICU4J uses a class named "ArabicShaping", there is some differences between arabic and persian scripts, for example, these characters exist in persian, but not in arabic. ( گ چ پ ژ )
ArabicShaping doesnt know how to deal with persian chars unfortunately

Comment: The same problem exists in Urdu and Iraqi